# Selecting multiple values from the same column but under different conditions

Tags: sql

I have a poorly formed table like this:

```
id| order_id | meta_key | meta_value
1 | 14 | 'cost'| 100
2 | 14 | 'tax' | 5
3 | 14 | 'sku' | q-1061
```

I want to select the cost, tax, sku for each order in the table, that is:

```
order_id|cost|tax|sku
14 | 100 | 5 | q-1061
```

Assuming there are 3 rows for each order, what is the fastest way of doing it?

Comment: Look for `Conditional Aggregate` or `Pivot`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want this, a simple way to pivot table:

```
SELECT
    order_id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key='cost' THEN meat_value END) AS cost,
    MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key='tax' THEN meat_value END) AS tax,
    MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key='sku' THEN meat_value END) AS sku
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY order_id
```

Comment: This works too. Thanks! I think pivot table will be faster than self joins.

Answer (score 1):

If each attribute can only occur exactly once, you can use a self join:

```
select t1.order_id, 
       t1.meta_value as cost, 
       t2.meta_value as tax, 
       t3.meta_value as sku
from the_table t1 
  join the_table t2 on t1.order_id = t2.order_id and t2.meta_key = 'tax'
  join the_table t3 on t1.order_id = t2.order_id and t2.meta_key = 'sku'
where t1.meta_key = 'cost';
```

If you have an index on `(meta_key, order_id)` this should be fairly efficient.

Comment: This is what I did too, but I wasn't sure if it's the most efficient way. Thanks a lot!